# Using local image assets in dart documentation comments

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

How can you use local assets in a dart documentation comment? This works fine when using a webbased url,, like so:

```
/// ![A row of icons representing a pink heart, a green musical note, and a blue umbrella](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/icon.png)
```

What I would like to do is reference some image assets I have in my assets folder and display that. Something like this:

```
///![](/assets/some/local/path.png)
///![](/assets/some/other/path.svg)
```

But I cannot get any relative path to work, is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely satisfying, but I just made a shell script to copy images that are part of the documentation into the right place in the generated HTML tree, viz:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
cd `dirname $0`
dartdoc
cd lib
for f in `find . -name '*.comments' -print` ; do
    dir=`basename $f .comments`
    cp -r $f ../doc/api/$dir
done
cd ..
```

ObRant:  It disappoints me that documentation generation tools often don't generally this (at least AFAIK).  Visual communication can greatly improve documentation!

For example, consider this bit of Java.  The UML is a big help in understanding the structure.  http://spritely.jovial.com/javadocs/index.html?edu/calpoly/spritely/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

This works for public repos.

```
///![my image](https://myoctocat.com/assets/images/base-octocat.svg)
```

and this works for private (displays a link in intellij idea, not the image).

```
/// [private repo link](https://github.com/atreeon/xyz/blob/abc/x.png?raw=true)
```

Again, not completely satisfying but it is another work around.