# Display an image from the asset in the documentation

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, comments, dartdoc

I'm writing documentation about a variable and I would like to include an image that is inside the project. For example:

```
assets/
 |- icons/
 |   |- my-image.svg
lib/
 |- my_file.dart
```

I know it is possible to display an image from an URL, but what about one from a file?

Those were my unsuccessful tries:

```dart
// lib/my_file.dart

/// The image attempt:
/// ![](assets/icons/my-image.svg)
/// ![](../assets/icons/my-image.svg)
const myVariable = 0;
```

But it doesn't work:

[image]

---

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

There is already an issue on GitHub: [#2390](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2390)
and also a related thread: [Using local image assets in dart documentation comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204384/using-local-image-assets-in-dart-documentation-comments)

Effectively, web urls are working, but relative paths aren't, because VSCode doesn't support that. It tries to open the files relative to its application directory. But I can't confirm that for Windows either, because for me, not even absolute paths are working...

So if your project lives in a public repository anyways, you could just use a web url.

Answer (score 0):

1:open pubspec.yaml and click "Pub get"

2:

```
Image.asset("assets/icons/my-image.svg",width: 100,height: 100,)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I don't want to display the image in the app (this is already done), I want to display it in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

So i think you want to let the variable hold the asset image path so do this

1. Go to pubspecs.yaml file and add this

   flutter:
   assets:
   - assets/icons/my-image.svg
   Then run `flutter pub get`

then you can use the image this way

```
//let the variable hold the image path
const myVariable = "assets/icons/my-image.svg";


//to display on widget
Image.asset(myVariable);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I don't want to display the image in the app (this is already done), I want to display it in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using external url

```
/// Asset derived from `assets/images/icon_inactive_account.svg`.
///
/// <img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/Flutter/assets/images/icon_inactive_account.svg" alt="icon_inactive_account" width="30" height="30" />
String get icon_inactive_account => 'assets/images/icon_inactive_account.svg';
```

or internal absolute path like this

```
/// Asset derived from `assets/images/icon_inactive_account.svg`.
///
/// <img src="/Users/Computer/Documents/Project/Flutter/assets/images/icon_inactive_account.svg" alt="icon_inactive_account" width="30" height="30" />
String get icon_inactive_account => 'assets/images/icon_inactive_account.svg';
```